# Unknown exception when validating password field in Xamarin Forms Cross Platform App

Tags: c#, validation, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to validate a text and a password field for empty values using following code:

```
if (txtUsername.Text.Trim().Length > 0 && txtPassword.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
{
    //Some code for successful validation
}
else
    DisplayAlert("Required Fields Empty", "Please enter username and password.", "OK");
```

The code is executing nicely when I remove `&& txtPassword.Text.Trim().Length > 0` from it. But with this code included, it's showing following exception:

```
An unhandled exception occured.
```

And no other detail for this exception is mentioned. So, please if someone could tell me why this is happening and where can I find logs that may contain exception details?

**UPDATE**

After using try...catch, I found that the `Text` property of password field is `NULL`. What could be the reason?

Comment: use try/catch to catch the Exception

Comment: @Jason oh I am an idiot I forgot to use try and catch. Thanks. But it's showing `Text` property of password field `NULL`. Why so?

Comment: probably because the user hasn't entered any text?  Use String.IsNullOrEmpty() instead of testing the length

Comment: @Jason if that's the case then why it is working correctly for empty username field?

Comment: I don't know - maybe you are initializing it somewhere?  Or possibly the behavior is different if the password option is set?  Regardless, you should not assume that an object is non-null before using it

Comment: Can you show us how txtUsername and txtPassword is being defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`txtPassword.Text` is `null`. Change your code to:

```
if ((txtUsername.Text != null) && (txtPassword.Text != null) && (txtUsername.Text.Trim().Length > 0) && (txtPassword.Text.Trim().Length > 0))
```

if you want the else to be executed in the case one of them is `null`. Otherwise use `try`-`catch`. The reason of `txtPassword.Text` being `null` should be searched for either in the initialization or in your code, if somewhere it is being set to `null`.